# tojson() does not return all related models

Tags: laravel, frontend, laravel-5.5, eloquent

I am working on laravel 5.5 project

i have four tables as following:-

1- Subject model (has following relations)

```
public function types()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Types');
}
public function areas()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Area');
}
public function articles()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Article');
}
```

2- Area and Types has many to many relation with Subject model

```
public function subjects()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Subjects');
}
```

3- Article has 1 to many relation with Subject

```
public function subjects()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Subjects');
}
```

The below controller will  search for subject by keyword, select type or area and return value as json using toJson() and return results to view:-

```
public function search(Request $request)
{
    //start search//
    $get_Subjects = new Subject();
    $get_Subjects = $get_Subjects ->newQuery();

    if($request->term != '')
    {
       $get_Subjects->with('articles')->whereHas('articles', function ($query) use ($request){
            $query->where('title', 'LIKE', '% '.$request->term.' %')
            ->orwhere('abstract', 'LIKE', '% '.$request->term.' %')
            ->orwhere('fullCitation', 'LIKE', '% '.$request->term.' %');
        })
        ->where(function($query) use ($request){

            $query->where('name', 'LIKE', '%'.$request->term.'%');
        });
    }if($request->area != '28')
    {
        // search for the selected area
        $get_Subjects->with('areas')->whereHas('areas', function($query) use ($request){
            $query->where('area_id', $request->area);
        });
    }
    if($request->type!= '36')
    {
        // search for the selected types
        $get_Subjects->with('types')->whereHas('types', function($query) use ($request){
            $query->where('type_id', $request->type);
        });
    }

    $subjects = $get_Subjects->tojson();
    return View::make('public.search', compact('subjects'));
}
```

the issue is when i search by keyword the returned json only include related articles, and if i search by area i only get related areas()

while if i did not use json and access variable from blade i can access all related models even though it is the same query
i tried to use load() but it did not work

any help will be valuable

**============Update===========**

i tried using load() as follow

```
$subjects= $get_subjects->get();
$subjects= $subjects->load('articles', 'areas', 'types')->tojson();
```

when search by keyword, the json does have related relations
but they are empty

when search by area or type, the json does have related relation

which mean if i search in the subject table only which is the 1st case i wont get related model with it

please need your help

Comment: What's the problem with `load` method?

Comment: @Pavel based on my search laod method shoud return model with all its relations but after trying it did not do anything the output are the same while using get()->tojson() or load()

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding the `->get()` method before the `->toJson()` method?

`$subjects = $get_Subjects->get()->toJson();`

`get()` will run the query and return models. `toJson()` should then work as you expect.

### Update

I would write your code like this to start with. (I haven't tested this).

It seems like you are using the `whereHas` the wrong way.  The subject table should have the `area_id` and `type_id` fields, so `whereHas` isn't needed... this might not be the case, but it seems like it should be based on the info you provided.

```
public function search(Request $request)
{
    $get_Subjects = new Subject();
    $get_Subjects = $get_Subjects ->newQuery();
    $with = [];


    if($request->term != '') {
       $with[] = 'articles';
       $subjects = $get_Subjects->whereHas('articles', function ($query) use ($request){
            $query->where('title', 'LIKE', '% '.$request->term.' %')
            ->orwhere('abstract', 'LIKE', '% '.$request->term.' %')
            ->orwhere('fullCitation', 'LIKE', '% '.$request->term.' %');
        })
        ->where('name', 'LIKE', '%'.$request->term.'%');
    }

    if($request->area != '28') {
        $with[] = 'areas';
        $get_Subjects->where('area_id', $request->area);
    }

    if($request->type!= '36') {
        $with[] = 'types';
        $get_Subjects->where('type_id', $request->type);
    }

    $subjects = $get_Subjects->with($with)->get()->toJson();

    return View::make('public.search', compact('subjects'));
}
```